# OrderBy is not working with alias in doctrine symfony2

Tags: php, oracle, case, symfony-2.8

what i need

> i  need sort alias.

symfony code

```
$qb->addSelect("(CASE WHEN  (priority LIKE  '%High%') THEN 1
       WHEN  (priority LIKE '%Medium%') THEN 2

       ELSE 3 END) AS  prioritys ");
```

sorting code

```
       priority  column name of view/table.

       prioritys  is alias.

      $qb->orderBy('priority','ASC');   //works because here im accessing column from table/view.

      $qb->orderBy('prioritys','ASC');   //doesnot works.
```

Error on using Alias

> Error : [Semantical Error] line 0, col 173 near 'prioritys ASC,': Error: 'prioritys' is not defined.

any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: *doesnot works* means do you get any error? or it is not sorting the results?

Comment: Also you could get the raw query generated by doctrine like `$qb->getSql()` and see if there is some issue or run this raw query on your database to verify

Answer (score 0):

```
$qb->orderBy('prioritys','ASC');   // it should work, check symfony2 doc.
```

As per the major databases, we can use column alias name in order by clause. So check your front end.

If not supported then use CASE expression in order by clause like below

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN priority LIKE '%High%' THEN 1 WHEN priority LIKE '%Medium%' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

Comment: I'm not good in front end. I can suggest below coding (if column alias not working in order by clause)
$qb->orderBy("(CASE WHEN  (priority LIKE  '%High%') THEN 1
       WHEN  (priority LIKE '%Medium%') THEN 2
       ELSE 3 END)");

Comment: soory it giving err  Error: Expected end of string, got 'CASE'